# How to add modified files in a directory to the index, but still ignore untracked files?

Tags: git

Usually I use `git commit -a` or `git add -a` to quickly add all of the files which are in the repo, which have been changed.

At times I want to commit a subset of what was changed. Here we specify them explicitly.

But I want to do something more nuanced now: Suppose my git repo has two sub projects inside of it and i want to make a commit for sub-project A, where I have inside the `A/` dir (1) a bunch of temporary files not checked into git and which I do NOT want to add to the index, and (2) multiple files which have been checked in which have changed, which I want to add to the index in one fell swoop of a command.

I am aware that if I modify my gitignore to fully encapsulate all possible types of temporary files, then I may use `add -a` to achieve this easily. However this isn't really very practical because directories tend to accumulate "extra items" in them.

Does such a git command exist?

Comment: It's certainly possible to write a small script which parses git status porcelain output and adds the files individually. I'm hoping something exists to do this that's built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update all tracked files in A:

```
git add -u A
```

From [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

> -u,
>   --update
>
> Update the index just where it already has an entry matching `<pathspec>`. This removes as well as modifies index entries to match the working tree, but adds no new files.
>
> If no `<pathspec>` is given when `-u` option is used, all tracked files in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).